# Android Email sending failed with error Fail to send: IOException while sending message

Tags: android

I have a mail sending application which sends email along with attachment. Every this is working fine except the attachment part. I am using this [code](http://verticalchallenge.org/archives/1906). But I dont know what is missing or what is wrong in this code. please help. here is Attachment part.

```
    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

In my main activity I am using

```
public final static String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "/Images_Book/";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String mailBody = "Email is send along with attachment";
    Mail m = new Mail("FTP backup failed", mailBody);
    try {
        m.addAttachment(path);
        m.send();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: here is stack trace 
07-10 21:03:29.312: W/Trace(3972): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-10 21:03:29.332: D/gralloc_goldfish(3972): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-10 21:03:29.382: W/Trace(3972): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-10 21:03:29.433: W/Trace(3972): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-10 21:03:31.173: D/dalvikvm(3972): GC_CONCURRENT freed 289K, 14% free 2708K/3120K, paused 72ms+5ms, total 108ms
07-10 21:03:32.722: E/MAIL(3972): fail to send:IOException while sending message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 public final static String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "/Images_Book/filetobeattached.ext";
```

Instead of

```
public final static String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "/Images_Book/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your function as below

```
public void addAttachment(File filename) throws Exception {
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename.getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

}